# Как узнать размер Java объекта

Tags: java

Как узнать какое количество байт занимает тот или иной объект в java во время работы программы , к примеру я использую ArrayList и заполняю его данными, как узнать сколько оперативной памяти занимает этот ArrayList во время работы программы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477260/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8?rq=1

Comment: Вам достаточно собственной памяти? Или Вы хотите, чтобы рекурсивно по ссылкам размер объектов посчитался?