# Получить размер List<SomeClass>

Tags: java, коллекции, рефлексия

Господа, помогите разобраться с рефлексией. Есть `SuperClass` класс и класс `SomeClass`:

```java
public class SuperClass {
    private List<SomeClass> listClass;
    
    public SuperClass(){
        this.listClass = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // ... getter and setter listClass
}

public class SomeClass {}
```

Как с помощью рефлексии получить размер свойства `listClass` класса `SuperClass`? Желательно через вызов метода `getListClass`.

Comment: Что такое "размер свойства"?

Comment: рефлексия тебе зачем? если у тебя есть геттер то количество элементов класса ты можешь получить из списка. размер SomeClass можно посчитать и руками, если он не очень сложный, из приведенного кода не понятно насколько.

Comment: вообще-то короче никак для явы вы этот точный размер наверное не сможете посчитать просто, все зависит от того что вы хотите получить. вот ссылка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477260/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Все усложняется тем, что элементы списка (метаданные могут занимать места больше чем скажем класс с одной-двумя переменными без методов и функций). а если ваш класс содержит другие ссылочные типы, например списки то считать будет еще сложнее.

Comment: Я хочу получить кол-во объектов в коллекции `listClass`.

Comment: Решение моего вопроса тут -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237820/reflection-get-the-size-of-listsomeclass/64237917#64237917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение кол-ва элементов списка из Getter метода другого класса, полученного и вызванного рефлексией.

```
// Получаем метод .getListClass()
Method method = SuperClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("getListClass");
// Открываем доступ к методу
method.setAccessible(true);
// Вызываем данный метод, результат сохраняем (null если method статичный, объект класса SomeClass, на котором мы вызываем данный метод)
List<SomeClass> list = (List<SomeClass>) method.invoke(null);
// Закрываем доступ к методу
method.setAccessible(false);

// Выводим количество полей в данном списке
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: спасибо... как оказывается все очень элементарно и просто!!!